# Looking for a live audio-only stream of NASA TV or JSC/ISS loops

Tags: nasa, reference-request, audio

I recently installed an old iMac G3 machine just for the fun of it, but it doesn't play YouTube videos for obvious reasons, so I can't use it to play NASA TV in any form. However, audio streams is something it can handle quite nicely, so I wonder if there are any audio-only (no YouTube or any fancy video codecs) streams that I ca listen to, for NASA TV broadcast or for ISS any public loops.